# Composer.phar difference between | and ||

Tags: php, composer-php, semantic-versioning

What is the difference between pipe and douoble pipe in composer.json file? For example:

```
"^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0"
```

and

```
'^1.0.0|^2.0.0'
```

Comment: From what I found, they're the same. May not be right though

Comment: || it is treated as logical OR

Comment: @Shanukk ok, so what is the difference between logical or and single pipe?

Answer (score 22):

They're the same.

If you look into the VersionParser class (https://github.com/composer/semver/blob/1dd67fe56c0587d0d119947061a6bfc9863c101c/src/VersionParser.php#L237) you can see the following code:

```
$orConstraints = preg_split('{\s*\|\|?\s*}', trim($constraints));
```

As we can see in the regex, they're is a ? after the second pipe, making it optional.

It seems that only the double pipe is documented though.
 (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#range)

Comment: The single pipe is deprecated but retained for backwards compatibility. Your preg_split reference is spot on.

Comment: This is also discussed in this issue [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6755). They removed the documentation for a single pipe but it still remains functional for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

I thinks it´s the old syntax of the composer OR logical operator.
I found this reference: [http://qpleple.com/understand-composer-versions](http://qpleple.com/understand-composer-versions/) (search for the pipe character)

In the introduction it says:

> Here are some extracts from Composer's documentation reorganized to
>   better understand how package versions and stability work

but I couldn't found any reference in current composer documentation, then I assume this is from an old version of the docs